# How to capture the line added / deleted / modified for the VSCode extension api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing the extension for VS Code and i need to capture the line added / deleted in the editor. Basically the issue i have is. I have created a diagnostic collection for a opened document say on Line 5, Postiion 2.
When a user edits the text document say added a line, the position changes. But the diagnostic data that is displayed in problems is still points to the old line 5.
What is the way to solve this, was thinking is there any possibility to capture the line added / deleted events of editor and update the line numbers.

Comment: when the file content changes analyze it and update the reported problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(event => {
    console.log(event);
  })
```

will be fired when any `TextDocument` is changed (not just saved).  It does so on a *character-by-character basis* though (except pastes/deletions which happen all at once).

There is the information you are looking for in the `event` object, like

`event.document.filename`   // which document was changed

`event.contentChanges`     // an array of changes

from which you can get the actual change(s) made to the document plus things like

`event.contentChanges[0].range.start.line` // the line where the change started on

On deletions, you are not given the actual text that was deleted, but the result, an empty string, but you still can get the `range` of the change - which has your two `start` and `end` Positions, each of which has a line number component to it.

I guess you could keep track of these changes and only do your calculations on a `onDidSaveTextDocument(event)` if you want to do them in bulk on a save.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mark , the data that comes in the event.contentChanges[0] is strange.

For example When an enter key is pressed with a new line in the data, what i am getting is

Range Length : 0, Offset : 462
Range data Start Line : 26, Pos : 1, End : 26, Pos : 1

Start and end are exactly the same

And also, when i copy and paste say 3 lines of code, what i get is

Range Length : 0, Offset : 464
Range data Start Line : 27, Pos : 1, End : 27, Pos : 1, single line : true

In both the cases, i have same start and end, any suggestions here

Comment: I think these are correct results.  The `range` is the range over which the change is made.  So with nothing selected, there is no `range.length` but the `start` and `end` would be exactly the same point in the dicument.  Try selecting the last word in a line and then inserting a newline, you will then get a range.length and start/end determined by where the replacement occurred - the selected text.

Comment: When you paste text - if nothing is selected to replace - again the `range.length` should be `0` and `start/end` positions are the point of insertion.  It would be nice if you got the result too after insertion, but you don't, you get information about the change not the resulting document directly.  But from examining what was inserted you can figure out whether there were any newlines, on W10 I see literal `\r\n` (probably different on Mac/linux) within the reported `text` - so you could from the `start.line` figure out how many lines were added.

Comment: One idea is to take the `event.contentChanges[n].text` information and run a `string.match` or similar against `textDocument.getText()` to figure out the index of insertion + length of insertion for end point and translate those into `Positions` with `textDocument.positionAt()`  - since this happens as each character is added/deleted or upon a paste/cut if your files are long you'll have to see what performance is like.  Just *spitballin` on this idea...

Comment: Thanks this seems to be a good suggestion.